# File Downloader with Java Commons IO stuck at 1MB/s+

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

Lately I've been experimenting with Java and Commons IO trying to create a web file downloader, however I've encountered a problem, in fact it seems that the file download speed does not exceed 1MB/s while the same download from the browser runs smoothly at 3MB /s. Could you help me? I would be really grateful.

This is my downloader code:

```
package com.application.steammachine;

import com.github.junrar.Archive;
import com.github.junrar.Junrar;
import com.github.junrar.exception.RarException;
import com.github.junrar.rarfile.FileHeader;
import com.github.junrar.volume.FileVolumeManager;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.ini4j.Wini;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.URL;

public class Downloader extends Task<Void> {

    private URL url;
    private String fileName;
    private Game game;

    public Downloader(URL url, String fileName, Game game) {
        this.url = url;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public class ProgressListener implements ActionListener {

        private double bytes = 0;
        private double mbDownloaded = 0;
        private double fileSize = 0;
        private double lastMB = 0;
        private long initialTime;
        private double speed = 0;
        private String downloadedText = "";
        private String sizeText;

        public ProgressListener(double fileSize){
            this.fileSize = fileSize;
            initialTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bytes = ((DownloadCountingOutputStream) e.getSource()).getByteCount();
            updateProgress(bytes, fileSize);
            mbDownloaded = round(bytes/1e+6, 2);

            if(fileSize >= 1073741824){ //>= 1GB
                double temp = ((fileSize/1e+6)/1024);
                sizeText = round(temp,2) + " GB";
            }else {
                double temp = (fileSize/1e+6);
                sizeText = round(temp,2) + " MB";
            }

            if(mbDownloaded >= 1024){
                downloadedText = String.valueOf(round(mbDownloaded/1024,2));
            }else{
                downloadedText = String.valueOf(mbDownloaded);
            }

            if((System.nanoTime() - initialTime) >= (Math.pow(10, 9))){
                speed = round((mbDownloaded - lastMB), 3);
                initialTime = System.nanoTime();
                lastMB = mbDownloaded;
            }

            updateMessage(String.valueOf(speed)+"MB/s,"+String.valueOf(downloadedText + "/" + sizeText));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        URL dl = this.url;
        File fl = null;
        String x = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {

            updateMessage("Searching files...,---/---");

            fl = new File(Settings.getInstallPath() +"/"+ this.fileName);
            os = new FileOutputStream(fl);
            is = dl.openStream();

            DownloadCountingOutputStream dcount = new DownloadCountingOutputStream(os);

            double fileSize = Double.valueOf(dl.openConnection().getHeaderField("Content-Length"));

            ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener(fileSize);
            dcount.setListener(progressListener);

            IOUtils.copy(is, dcount, 512000 );

            updateMessage("Concluding...,Almost finished");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
            updateMessage(",");
            this.cancel(true);
            return null;

        } finally {

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);


            updateMessage(",");
            updateProgress(0, 0);
            this.cancel(true);
            return null;

        }
    }


    protected static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(value));
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

}
```

This is the DownloadCountingOutputStream class, which i use for keeping track of the download status:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DownloadCountingOutputStream extends CountingOutputStream {

    private ActionListener listener = null;

    public DownloadCountingOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void setListener(ActionListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterWrite(int n) throws IOException {
        super.afterWrite(n);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, null));
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1):

First, there are a couple of simple things you could try to speed up the transfers:

1. Try using a larger transfer buffer size.  Change the 8K buffer size to 64K or 512K.
2. Get rid of the `DownloadCountingOutputStream` and transfer directly to the `FileOutputStream`.

These should be simple to try ... and they *may* help a bit.

---

On a Linux system, it may also be worthwhile to replace Apache `IOUtils.copy` call with code that uses the kernel's zero-copy transfer support.  See [Efficient data transfer through zero copy](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-zerocopy/) for an explanation.

The example in the article is for uploading using `transferTo`, but downloading using `transferFrom` should be analogous.  The article claims a 65% speedup for large file transfers compared with conventional Java I/O.  But that is likely to depend on the characteristics of your network connection.

Comment: i tried increasing buffer size to 512K but it made no difference at all; i can't change DownloadCountingOutputStream method because i use it for traking download status, let me edit my question so that you can see

Comment: Looking at `DownloadCountingOutputStream`, I am suspicious that that is the real cause of the performance issue.  Try an experiment.  Remove it anyway to see what happens.  'Cos if you can't remove it, zero-copy won't work either.